# Send Mms over HTTPS insteadof HTTP

Tags: android, http, https, mms

at present the mms sent is over HTTP , and port is 80.
I want to change mms over HTTPS , port changed to 443.

Can MMS be sent using HTTPS ?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, No and doesn't need. OMA-MMS doesn't support https as now, and almost all carriers doesn't set HTTPS mms server. also as that will be sent using carrier 5G/LTE/WCDMA network so don't need to encrypt the content.